# How can we describe the class of trajectories around a point mass in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, orbital-motion, geodesics

As per the answers to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/352016/spiral-trajectory-under-gravity), a Newtonian gravitational trajectory of a test particle about an ideal isolated point mass is always a conic section.

An ideal point mass in GR is a black hole, either Schwarzchild or Kerr, right?  Consider all ideal free-fall trajectories (timelike geodesics) about this singularity (including the ones that end up getting sucked into it).  Are there any generalizations or meaningful names we can attach to the class of such trajectories?  Probably nothing as simple as "conic sections", but still something?  And would it change if you let the spacetime be asymptotically de Sitter?

Comment: I mean, calling them "geodesics" is a meaningful name but it's probably not the sort of thing you're looking for.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Haha, point taken.  I admit it's kind of vague but I'm hoping there's some mathematical insight to be unearthed here...

Comment: If you google for images of Kerr geodesics, you will see how complicated they are.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#/media/File:Generic_geodesic_orbit_around_a_Kerr_black_hole.png

Comment: Schwarzschild orbits are generally not closed and therefore are not going to fall into nice categories like the Newtonian two body case. This is due to Bertrand's theorem, stating that there are only two central forces where all bound orbits are also closed orbits ($r$ and $r^{-1}$), which relativistic bodies do not obey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timelike geodesics around a Kerr (or Schwarzschild) black hole are not nearly as nice as their Newtonian counterpart, and certainly cannot be described as something as simple as a conic section. Here is an example of a generic bound geodesic in Kerr:

[image]

However, the geodesics in Kerr spacetime form an integrable system (thanks to a hidden symmetry), and can generally be solved in closed analytic form (see e.g. [0906.1420](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1420) or [1906.05090](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.05090)). This even the case for [geodesics in Kerr-(Anti-)deSitter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.6117).

In all but the simplest cases these solution come in the form of [elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function). The combinations that appear, however, are much more complicated than the relatively simple case of the conic sections (which also require elliptic functions to be described).